# Override Minicart.php Block magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, mini-cart, override-block

I have try to doing override minicart.php block but unfortunately not getting success of override.

you can see below code what i have implemented :

```
    <blocks>
        <test>
            <class>ABC_Test_Block</class>
        </test>
        <minicart_head>
            <rewrite>
                <minicart_heads>ABC_Test_Block_Cart_Minicart</minicart_heads>
            </rewrite>
        </minicart_head>
    </blocks>
```

can you please guide for resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i resolve the issue of override minicart block for custom module.

you can use below code :

```
    <blocks>
        <test>
            <class>ABC_Test_Block</class>
        </test>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart_minicart>ABC_Test_Block_Cart_Minicart</cart_minicart>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
```

It's working absolutely fine.  Thanks